# Single SQL statement based on the existence of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have two tables in a database

**Table1**

| T1ID | T1Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | T1V1 |
| 2 | T1V2 |
| 3 | T1V3 |
| 4 | T1V4 |

**Table 2**

| T2ID | T1FK | T2Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | T2V1 |
| 2 | 3 | T2V2 |

Please note that **Table2** has a foreign key, that references **T1ID** in **Table1**. Also note that not all entries in **Table1** have corresponding entries in **Table2**.

Now, I would like to use a **SINGLE** SQL statement to do both of the two following

1. If there are corresponding entries in **Table2** related to **Table1**, then run the following statement

   `SELECT t1.*, t2.T2Value FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.T1ID = t2.T1FK WHERE t1.T1ID = 2`
2. If there aren't any corresponding entries in **Table2** related to **Table1**, then run the following statement (notice that `NULL` is returned instaed of `t2.T2Value`)

   `SELECT t1.*, NULL FROM Table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.T1ID = 4`

(Please note that t1.T1ID is supplied by the program, so this value will change. I am just showing you what I need)

How do I combine both the above statements into a single statement?

Thanks.

Comment: *If there aren't any corresponding entries in Table2 related to Table1* do you mean for t1.T1ID = 2 or there is no row in Table2 with T1FK that references any T1ID?

Comment: @forpas Now that you mention it, I'm wondering that as well.

Comment: @forpas - I mean there is no row in Table2 with T1FK referencing any T1ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` will do what you want. For example:

```
select t1.*, t2.t2value
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.t1id = t2.t1fk
where t1.t1id = <parameter>
```

For example:

- If the parameter is 2, then a related row is found and the query returns the value of it (`t2.t2value`).
- If the parameter is 4, then no related row is found and the query returns NULL in its place.